# Auto populate cells in excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have a dropdown on column A. Column B is dependent on the option that will be selected in column A. How can I have everything on column B automatically show once I have selected an option in column A?

Let's say the options in the dropdown (in column A) are countries. Then once I click a country (from column A), all the cities of that country would be shown in column B automatically. Is this possible?

Comment: It is possible. Do you have the list of the possibilities for B dropdown for each selected A dropdown option? The answer depends on how this list was made.

Answer (score 2):

You can use either a lookup function like VLookup, Index/Match, or you could use a VBA Worksheet_Change event. If you need more help with this, edit your question and provide more details.